# Kinesis read from logstash

Tags: amazon-web-services, logstash, logstash-configuration, amazon-kinesis

How can we implement aws Kinesis to read from logstash ?

Do we have to install the plugins for Kinesis in Logstash on EC2 ?If so how?

Answer (score 2):

You need to install [logstash-output-kinesis](https://github.com/samcday/logstash-output-kinesis) plugin on the logstash server on EC2 instance and then configure the data to be sent to Kinesis

The complete configuration on how to supply authentication, etc are provided on [logstash-output-kinesis](https://github.com/samcday/logstash-output-kinesis)

The output side of your configuration [in simple case] would then be

```
output {
  kinesis {
    stream_name => "logs-stream"
    region => "ap-southeast-2"
  }
}
```

Comment: It took a while for aws-kinesis dashboard to respond to the logstash but it is working,Thanks.